# dynamic variable written into regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a simple regular expression:

```
str.match(/SK=([\w‌​\-]+)/i);
```

I would like the `SK` part to be dynamic so I can return the match for `SK=`, `WP=` etc...

So I'm looking for something like:

```
var attr = 'SK';
str.match(/' + attr  + '=([\w‌​\-]+)/i);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the constructor syntax to create your regex:

```
var myRegex = new RegExp(attr + "([\\w‌​\\-]+)","i");
```

and then:

```
str.match(myRegex);
```

See here (emphasis mine): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

> The literal notation provides compilation of the regular expression when the expression is evaluated. **Use literal notation when the regular expression will remain constant.** For example, if you use literal notation to construct a regular expression used in a loop, the regular expression won't be recompiled on each iteration.
>
> The constructor of the regular expression object, for example, new RegExp("ab+c"), provides runtime compilation of the regular expression. **Use the constructor function when you know the regular expression pattern will be changing, or you don't know the pattern** and are getting it from another source, such as user input.

Comment: Thanks, but this returns null, I know the regex is valid because its been tested, but for some reason it doesn't work when using in RegExp...

Comment: @keeg: Yeah, you need to use double slash because it's now a string. So `new RegExp(attr + "([\\w\\-]+)","i");`. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/93Jb3/

Comment: I had a feeling it was a slash issue! Thank you!